# Is that possible to build a C# console exe without the Main entry?

Tags: c#, console, program-entry-point

I am new to C# programming, currently I got one C# program without any .sln files, so I just imported the whole directory with the console mode. However, I could not find the Main entry files, in the previous output folder, I could find an executable file of console, I am not sure how to build this out. Is that possible to build the console executable file without "Main" entry?

Comment: No, you must always have some sort of `Main` entry-point. That said, you can easily add one by using the code from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1sx6ed2.aspx

Comment: Can't I build something like service or something like that to make the program runnable? I saw there is some configuration to setup which object could be launched, is that able to do this?

Comment: No: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506.aspx

Comment: Just add it yourself or use Project + Properties, Application tab, Output type = Class Library.  Which is surely the way it was built before if Main() is missing.  A telephone tends to be the proper tool.

Answer (score 1):

No, when you run the **exe** file your computer immediately looks for the "*Main*" method to run.  Otherwise all you have is a bunch of code and your computer doesn't know where to start when it opens your program.